# Search in whole .bash_history list with full-featured regex engine

Tags: bash, command-history, less

When I have to search backwards in the .bash_history list I want to see the timestamps as were created by HISTTIMEFORMAT. And the results have to end up in a pager, where regex can be used for searching.

Thus normally I use the command:

```
history | less -I -j $(($LINES/2))
```

But I don't know how to let less use a good regular expression engine out of the possibilities the operating system provides.

Now I have a solution which uses the regex capabilities of vim:

```
vim -u /root/.vimrc -M + <( history | less -I -j $(($LINES/2))  )
```

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer instead of putting it in the question.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve; `less` supports interactive regex searches with the `/` and `?` commands in a similar manner to `vim`.

Comment: correction to my code:

    vim -u /root/.vimrc -M + <( history  )

Comment: regarding:Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve; less supports interactive regex searches with the / and ? commands in a similar manner to vim. – 
bxm --- No, unfortunatly less does only support a restricted kind of regexes. Though the manpage of less says that less does use the regex as is provided by the oprating system, this is not true. The OS privides more than one kind of regexes. less does not alliw to choose which kind of regexes, i.e. which regex engine to use. Regards Anton Wessel

Comment: e.g. all with greediness less cannot handle.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have a solution which uses the regex capabilities of vim:

```
vim -u /root/.vimrc -M + <(history)
```

Regards

antondhidh